# draw an oval shape around the text on canvas

Tags: android

I want to draw an oval shape around the text on `Canvas`, I am displaying the 3 texts on `Canvas` using `drawwText()` method.

Now when I click on a particular text, I need to draw an oval around that text and again when we click on another text, the oval shape should appear on the clicked text. For this give me some code suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

use drawOval method().. here is the signature of the method..

```
public void drawOval (RectF oval, Paint paint)
```

RectF is class for drawing rectangle...whose constructor is defined as following...

```
RectF(x,y,x+width,y+height);
```

you can make its object as follows

```
RectF rect = new RectF(x,y,x+width,y+height);...
```

now pass this object in drawOval method....

```
canvas.drawOval(rect,paint);
```

Comment: What if I want to draw half ellipse. When I use drawArc it draw semi circle.

Answer (score 2):

for resolution (480 x 800)

in onCreate()

```
setContentView(new SampleView(this));
```

create class

```
private static class SampleView extends View {

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        //1
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        RectF oval1 = new RectF(0, 0, 250,250);

        Paint p1 = new Paint();
        p1.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        canvas.drawText("Parent", 30, 50, p1);
        canvas.drawOval(oval1, paint);


        //2
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        RectF oval2 = new RectF(50, 50, 150, 150);

        Paint p2 = new Paint();
        p2.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        canvas.drawText("Child", 75, 75, p2);
        canvas.drawOval(oval2, paint);
    }

}
```